# Kusto/LogAnalytics data to pie chart

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

Could anyone give me an example code, how i can render this data in a pie chart?

I want a count of computers that are up to date or not, in each catagory.
I also get duplicate "computer" entries here as they have several entries at diffrent dates, i only want the last status.

[Example data - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR1nE.png)

Answer (score 0):

here's an option for one category (replace the group by key of `summarize` for the others):

```
datatable(computer:string, featureUpdateStatus:string, qualityUpdateStatus:string, securityUpdateStatus:string, lastScan:datetime)
[
    "c1", "not up-to-date", "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 14:03:50),
    "c1", "not up-to-date", "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 15:02:59),
    "c2", "not up-to-date", "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-06 11:44:40),
    "c2", "not up-to-date", "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 16:18:01),
    "c3", "up-to-date",     "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 13:39:09),
    "c3", "up-to-date",     "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 12:26:45),
    "c4", "not up-to-date", "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 16:18:01),
    "c4", "up-to-date",     "up-to-date", "up-to-date", datetime(2020-07-07 13:39:09),
]
| summarize arg_max(lastScan, *) by computer
| summarize count() by featureUpdateStatus
| render piechart
```